# Reset the dimension of all the matrixs in a list

Tags: r, list, apply, dimensions

Data: assume that I have a list of matrixs called `S`, which could be generated by:

```
S<-list(c(1:25),c(1:25),c(1:25),c(1:25))
```

Here is a feasible way which I want to optimize:

```
for (i in 1:length(S))
{
  dim(S[[i]])<-c(5,5)
}
```

After searching on the net, I tried to use `lapply` to apply a function over a list, and this is the code I have tried:

```
mat<-lapply(S, function(x) dim(x)<-c(5,5))
```

which only returns:

```
> mat
[[1]]
[1] 5 5

[[2]]
[1] 5 5

[[3]]
[1] 5 5

[[4]]
[1] 5 5
```

Question: I'm wondering if there is an inbuilt function which could apply a function over a list which doesn't require `return`, or there are some errors in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending your code attempt, you need to include an explicit or implicit `return` statement:

```
lapply(S, function(x) { dim(x) <- c(5, 5); return(x) })
lapply(S, function(x) { dim(x) <- c(5, 5); x; })
```

or faster by recasting every `list` entry as a `matrix`:

```
lapply(S, function(x) matrix(x, 5, 5))
```

or using `purrr::map`:

```
map(S, ~ matrix(., 5, 5))
```

---

### Benchmark comparison

[Edited by @HunterJiang]

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
N<-30
M<-30
S<-list(c(1:(N*M)),c(1:(N*M)),c(1:(N*M)),c(1:(N*M)))
mb <- microbenchmark(
  for_loop = { for (i in 1:length(S)) dim(S[[i]])<-c(N,M) },
  dim_plus_return = { S1<-lapply(S, function(x) { dim(x) <- c(N,M); return(x) }) },
  cast_matrix = { S1<-lapply(S, function(x) matrix(x, N,M)) },
  purrr_map = { S1<-map(S, ~ matrix(.,N,M)) },
  set_dim_directly = { S1<-lapply(S, `dim<-`, c(N,M)) }
)
mb
ggplot(mb, aes(expr, log10(time))) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  labs(y = "Time in log10 nanosec", x = "Method")
```

When N and M are small, says N=M=30, the speed of methods are:

```
Unit: microseconds
             expr      min       lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
         for_loop 2111.950 2236.298 2537.42270 2328.4735 2484.2055 4581.549   100
  dim_plus_return   10.264   12.633   32.91945   16.1855   19.3440 1641.794   100
      cast_matrix   11.054   13.423   27.40873   16.3830   18.9490 1068.213   100
        purrr_map   70.662   77.768   99.41636   93.1640  112.9015  199.748   100
 set_dim_directly    5.527    6.909    8.47230    7.8960    9.6720   22.502   100
```

But when N and M become larger, says N=M=3k, `lapply` gets slower than it used to be and `for` loop might be a proper way to do this.

```
Unit: milliseconds
             expr       min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
         for_loop  2.224456 20.83191 52.76189 41.72521  69.91993 180.9775   100
  dim_plus_return 35.930768 37.57671 68.63905 39.31620  74.14185 193.8300   100
      cast_matrix 48.220338 51.16917 79.73308 52.37871  87.31804 199.2859   100
        purrr_map 49.534089 51.21635 89.11881 61.12987 101.98780 195.1374   100
 set_dim_directly 35.151124 37.71112 67.72032 39.91919  74.97617 184.4943   100
```

**Conclusion:** `` S1<-lapply(S, `dim<-`, c(N,M)) `` fits the small dataset, and `for` loop could be faster when the dimension of the dataset is very large.

Comment: Or ``lapply(S, `dim<-`, c(5,5))``. But I don't think any of these are faster than the `for` loop.

Comment: @Roland For what it's worth: At least based on OPs sample data casting as matrix and using `purrr::map` are significantly faster than the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for several ways and careful test, I've Learned a lot!

Comment: @Roland I forgot the method from your comment in the benchmark analysis; setting `dim` directly seems to be the fastest method.

Comment: Just a thought: in my point of view, both of these methods need to re-generate a list and I have to write a code like `S<-lapply(S, `dim<-`, c(5,5))` , so maybe `for` loop will be the faster option than any of these when the dimension of the matrix become quite large, such as 10K*10K.

Comment: @HunterJiang Perhaps, but I would be surprised if that were the case. It might be interesting to re-run the benchmark comparison when generating matrices of larger dimensions.

Comment: @HunterJiang Nice one on the extended benchmark analysis:-) You were right with your projection on the efficiency of the `for` loop solution for larger matrices.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and effort!